# How to Drag line by its end points using rectangle as end points error?

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3.js and please forgive me if this sounds like a naive question. I have plotted a line (d3 v4) which can be draggable by its end points. The end points are rectangle.

The current output looks as below :

This is how it looks
[image]

The challenge that i am facing is - when i start dragging the point, the line seems to take its origin from the top left corner. When i drag the second point of the same line, the line drags / moves as expected.

The sample data looks as below :

[The sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yle9i.png)

Requesting your suggestions / inputs on how to fix the above issue.

Below is the attached code that i am using :

```js
var margin = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Creating the colour Category
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([390, 0]);

// Scale the range of the data

y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return Math.max(d.nonpromotedprice, d.promotedprice)*1.2; })]).nice();

// Line for the 1st Block
var lines = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('line')// attach a line
    .style("stroke", "#E6EAEE")
    .style("stroke-width", 8) // colour the line
    .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.x_value; }) // x position of the first end of the line
    .attr("y1", function (d) { return y(d.nonpromotedprice); }) // y position of the first end of the line
    .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.x_value; }) // x position of the second end of the line
    .attr("y2", function (d) { return y(d.promotedprice); });

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
    .attr("stroke-width", 0.7)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
        .tickSize(-400)
        .tickFormat("")); 
 
var topEndPoints = data.map(function (line, i) {
    return {
        'x': line.x_value,
        'y': line.nonpromotedprice,
        'marker': 'marker-start',
        'lineIndex': i
    };
});

var bottomEndPoints = data.map(function (line, i) {
    return {
        'x': line.x_value,
        'y': line.promotedprice,
        'marker': 'marker-end',
        'lineIndex': i
    };
});

var MiddleEndPoints = data.map(function (line, i) {
    return {
        'x': line.x_value,
        'y': line.avgprice,
        'marker': 'marker-middle',
        'lineIndex': i
    };
});
var endPointsData = topEndPoints.concat(bottomEndPoints, MiddleEndPoints);

// Pointer to d3 rectangles
var endPoints = svg
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(endPointsData)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr("width", 12)
    .attr("height", 8)
    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x - 6; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
    //.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
    //.attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
    //.attr('r',7)
    .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.x); })
    .call(d3.drag()
  //.origin(function(d) { return y(d.y); })
   .subject(function() { 
    var t = d3.select(this);
    return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
   })  
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));


// draw the logo
svg.selectAll("image")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return d.logo; })
    //.append("rect")  
    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_value - 13; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.nonpromotedprice + 35); })
    .attr("height", 25)
    .attr("width", 25);



function dragstarted() {
    d3.select(this).classed("active", true).attr('y', d.y = y(d3.event.y));
}

function dragged(d, i) {
    var marker = d3.select(this);

    // Update the marker properties
    marker
        //.attr('cx', d.x = d3.event.x)
        .attr('y', d.y = d3.event.y);
 

    // Update the line properties
    lines
        .filter(function (lineData, lineIndex) {
            return lineIndex === d.lineIndex;
        })
        .attr('x1', function (lineData) {
            return d.marker === 'marker-start' ? lineData.x1 = d.x : lineData.x1;
        })
        .attr('y1', function (lineData) {
            return d.marker === 'marker-start' ? lineData.y1 = d.y : lineData.y1;
        })

        .attr('x2', function (lineData) {
            return d.marker === 'marker-end' ? lineData.x2 = d.x : lineData.x2;

        })
        .attr('y2', function (lineData) {
            return d.marker === 'marker-end' ? lineData.y2 = d.y : lineData.y2;
        });
}

function dragended() {
    d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
  Shiny.setInputValue("pricechanged",
            {price: (d3.max(data, function (d) { return Math.max(d.nonpromotedprice, d.promotedprice); }) -(d3.event.y / 390)* d3.max(data, function (d) { return Math.max(d.nonpromotedprice, d.promotedprice); }))*1.19}, 
   {priority: "event"}
          );
    
}
```

Comment: what is your sample data?

Comment: @rioV8 - I have attached the sample data, in this case i am passing the data from the Rshiny to d3. Thanks.

Comment: draw your lines based upon a data structure that contains the `endPoints` records, and do not forget to take the inverse of the y-scale when you update the data-points